# Weird backlinks created from own domain

Tags: apache2, joomla

In Ahrefs I have noticed, that one of my webpages have weird (thousands) of backlinks which come from four own domains (and one IP from my own dedicated server).

For example: This URL (which is the suspicious one)

https://florida-paintings.art/industrie/verbindungstechnik/kleben/10314-dosierung-von-1k-acrylatklebstoff-mit-komplexen-dichtraupengeometrien

is a **backlink** to this one:

https://www.developmentscout.com/industrie/messtechnik/11934-caq-system

Another example: This URL (which is the suspicious one)

https://51.89.98.21/branche/gebaeudetechnik/11720-smart-panel-okw-gehaeuse

is a **backlink** to this one:

https://www.developmentscout.com/branche/mobile-arbeitsmaschine/11919-profi-drohne

The weird thing is also, that all the suspicious URL's have a canonical tag NOT the "right" one but rather a self-referencing tag to it's own URL.

The management of my domains is realized by the DNS server of OVH.

I have no clue "who" (CMS Joomla, Debian, ISP, etc.) is generating all these URL's. So if someone has an idea, I would much appreciate it!

Thanks Jens

---

Wow! Thanks for the answer Gerald. Yes, in the meantime I canceled the server IP address for the "florida-paintings.art"-domain, so this could not reachable anymore.

The second thing is also correct. I don't have any virtual host for the server IP. Didn't know that I have to. Below is an example ([www.aardvark.aaa](http://www.aardvark.aaa) shows "Hello World"). Does is look to work?

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx
        ServerName 51.89.98.21
        ServerAlias www.aardvark.aaa
        DocumentRoot /var/www/aardvark
    </VirtualHost>
    
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx
        ServerName 2001:41d0:700:3315::
        ServerAlias www.aardvark.aaa
        DocumentRoot /var/www/aardvark
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link doesn't work, so I can't comment on it. But the second is a simple case of a missing virtualhost. You don't have a virtualhost for the IP address of your server configured, so it uses the next best it can find for requests landing on the IP address directly. This happens to be the named domain. The CMS on the other hand has some FQDN links to the domain configured, for example in the footer. Relative URLs on the other hand stay with the requested servername, here the IP address.

Just add a virtualhost to your webserver for the IP address that doesn't show any content.